# How do I use getElementById in php echo

Tags: php

I have a problem trying to get element id from a modal inside PHP echo. I don't know if I'm doing it right. please help.

```
<?php 
echo'<button onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block' " style="width:auto;">Add stock</button>';
<?
```

I'm getting this error pointed to this command.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "id01", expecting "," or ";" in
```

Please help me out here. Thanks

Comment: escape your apostroph: `\'id01\'` and `\'block\'`

Comment: Why are you using echo for this to begin with, when nothing about this looks to be “dynamic” in any way? https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Answer (score 2):

Make sure when you're ending a PHP statement to use '?>' not '<?'  (without apostrophes).
also, escape the apostrophes.

```
<?php 
echo'<button onclick="document.getElementById(\'id01\').style.display=\'block\' " style="width:auto;">Add stock</button>';
?>
```